# Changing font size of an ebook in PDF format

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat, ebook, kindle

Is there any ways to change the font size of a whole book ( about 800 pages ) which is in PDF format ?  I've tried Adobe Acrobat's OCR , and well what it does is just increasing a single page's font , and even that simple page is not aligned anymore with the whole PDF ( I mean increasing the size , will cause u to loose like a half of the page cause the magnified words  can't be put into a single page and it does not change other pages on itself ).
Anyways to do so ? any help is greatly appreciated :)

- What I eventually wanna do is to be able to read the PDF on my Kindle Touch E-Reader which does NOT support Page Orientations ( And that really sucks !! ) and I really can't read PDFs while i have to read the words using a magnifier ! and the PDF to MOBI convert which Amazon does won't keep PDFs with images the same as before the conversion .

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be to use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) to produce a /mobi version of the ebook. You first convert from PDF to HTML, re-insert images as needed, then Calibre can read the HTM and produce a .mobi suitable for Kindle. You can then use the Kindle's font-size tools without the awkward zooming and scrolling needed for PDFs.

Changing font-size in a PDF means re-flowing the text. The same applies to changing the page size from Letter or A4 down to Kindle-sized. So far as I know there are no tools that can automate this for arbitrary PDF files.

Comment: Thanks :) But I've used calibre , it also messes things up when u have images inside your PDF , what does it mean to re-insert the images as needed ?